# AWS QuickSight, can I publish some report into my own web application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

My team and I are making a web application that needs to have reporting part in it. Can we display QuickSight dashboards in our application and how?

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: You can look at the official documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/embedding-dashboards.html)

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is now supported. Check the blog article on [Embed interactive dashboards in your application with Amazon QuickSight](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/embed-interactive-dashboards-in-your-application-with-amazon-quicksight/).

Comment: Thanks for your input! :)

Comment: This answer is out of date.

Answer (score 1):

Since November 2018, embedding dashboards is supported.